# CPUs jammed by SearchIndexer?

Tags: windows-7, search, cpu-usage

I was minding my own business scripting along, hunting down some docs on a library i used for a piece of code that i dusted off. I searched for a simple thing ('ex', with quotes) in the documents directory for the libraries that come with the scripting language i use, and shortly thereafter, both of my CPU's jammed themselves to 100% and it seems that SearchIndexer is the culprit. Did my search trigger an indexing party or something?

Comment: I turn the damn thing off - I'm happy to wait for a moment while it scans through everything, than wait less, but be constantly slowed by it eating my disk I/O for reasons I'm not entirely sure of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, however I don't think it will be permanent.

The Vista/Windows 7 search indexer is good, but it can be very resource heavy if not run in a while.

If I open Outlook for the first time in a week, it is common for my CPU to be at 100% for a few minutes whilst indexing, the same goes for if I just extract a huge file (I mean 1000+ files) to an indexed location.

Comment: As i write this it's been running for at least 20-30 minutes, and i requently see it pop up and do stuff.

Comment: Other times i mean.

Comment: If this is just the first time it is being run, leave it for a few hours to fully index everything. If it does it after that, you could have a problem, but it is hard to know without seeing the script and understanding in detail what it is actually doing